# Finding short path to Foundation

Tags: compass-sass, zurb-foundation, codekit

Can someone explain why the short path in my config.rb file isn't compiling:

```
require 'zurb-foundation'  # it fails
```

But when I specify the full path it does:

```
require "/Users/lukashillebrand/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.2/lib/zurb-foundation.rb";
```

I'm using CodeKit to compile and Foundation 4

Comment: what do you mean by 'compass' in the title..?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for your interest, by Compass I mean [compass-style.org](http://compass-style.org)

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer. The word "compass" has many meanings, let's just start with [the most known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass). Please try to clarify terms that might be not immediatelly obvious to other people. Also, please try to search&use tags for giving the better context for your question. I've moved the "compass" from title into the tags area as "compass-css", where every one can check the brief info on what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that CodeKit is apparently using the system ruby, and so the relative path is looking there.  Your full path is pointing to an `rvm` version, which is installed elsewhere.

The quick fix is temporarily switch `rvm` to the system ruby & gemset, and install `zurb-foundation` there:

```
$ rvm system
$ sudo gem install zurb-foundation
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me - I´ve had to change to my system ruby. Sorry for my late reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know zurb, just Ruby as a language/platform, and I think that if that first 'require' throws, then most probably some paths are not set up properly in your server environment.

Is Zurb distributed as a gem? Are other gems found well and are require'able by your code? If not, or if you don't know, try adding

```
require "rubygems"
```

as the very first line of your code (well, after some initial shebang and other comments). It should normally be invoked by the framework, somewhere before your file, but as I already said, I don't know Zurb. Maybe it simply does not do that for performance reasons.

Also, run some simple file in the same environment and inspect the `$:` variable, it should show you the paths that are searched for modules. If in very deadline'y times, you can even [temporarily push a new path to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167133/717732) (just replace the '.' with your target path), but it'd be best left as a last resort. Your zurb module seems to sit in Gems, so it should be found automatically.